# Datagridview items are showing up empty?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I was hoping you could help me with this little problem. I did this to add all my users accounts details to a datagridview and now the colums are all empty?

```
public DataTable GetResultsTable(string Username)
{
    using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
    {
        DataRow row = client.ExecuteQueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + Username + "'");
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Username".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Motto".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Email".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Homeroom".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Health".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Energy".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Age".ToString());
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        dr["Username"] = "" + row["username"] + "";
        dr["Motto"] = "" + row["motto"] + "";
        dr["Email"] = "" + row["mail"] + "";
        dr["Homeroom"] = "" + row["home_room"] + "";
        dr["Health"] = "" + row["health"] + "";
        dr["Energy"] = "" + row["energy"] + "";
        dr["Age"] = "" + row["age"] + "";
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
        return table;
    }
}
SqlDatabaseManager.Initialize();
  using (SqlDatabaseClient client  = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
  foreach (DataRow row2 in client.ExecuteQueryTable("SELECT * FROM users").Rows)
  {
      dataGridView1.DataSource = GetResultsTable((string)row2["username"]);
  }
```

my execute query is

```
public DataRow ExecuteQueryRow(string CommandText)
    {
        DataTable DataTable = ExecuteQueryTable(CommandText);
        return DataTable.Rows.Count > 0 ? DataTable.Rows[0] : null;
    }
```

Comment: can you update the question with your `ExecuteQueryRow` method code?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public DataRow GetResultsTable(string Username)
{
using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
{
    DataRow row = client.ExecuteQueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + Username + "'");

    DataRow dr = new DataRow;
    dr.Columns.Add("Username".ToString());
    dr.Columns.Add("Motto".ToString());
    dr.Columns.Add("Email".ToString());
    dr.Columns.Add("Homeroom".ToString());
    dr.Columns.Add("Health".ToString());
    dr.Columns.Add("Energy".ToString());
    dr.Columns.Add("Age".ToString());
    dr["Username"] = "" + row["username"] + "";
    dr["Motto"] = "" + row["motto"] + "";
    dr["Email"] = "" + row["mail"] + "";
    dr["Homeroom"] = "" + row["home_room"] + "";
    dr["Health"] = "" + row["health"] + "";
    dr["Energy"] = "" + row["energy"] + "";
    dr["Age"] = "" + row["age"] + "";

    return dr;
}
 }
    SqlDatabaseManager.Initialize();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Username".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Motto".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Email".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Homeroom".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Health".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Energy".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Age".ToString());
    using (SqlDatabaseClient client  = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
    foreach (DataRow row2 in client.ExecuteQueryTable("SELECT * FROM users").Rows)
  {
  table .Rows.Add( GetResultsTable((string)row2["username"]));
   }
  DataGridView.DataSourse=table ;
```